# Can circumstances arise?

Tags: collocation

Is it correct to  say:

> At the time, circumstances arose such that I had to leave the city.

in the meaning that situation got such that the speaker could not stay in the city anymore? Particularly, I am curious if one can say *arise* about circumstances or situation.

Comment: Using "arose" with "circumstances" is very idiomatic... I think you may want a comma after "At the time"... though I'm waffling.

Comment: @Catija Yes, I missed a comma indeed.

Comment: Arise:  to come into being; originate - Yes, it is not an uncommon expression: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circumstances+arise%2C+circumstances+arose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircumstances%20arise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircumstances%20arose%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I don't think circumstances are any less adept at levitation than situations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a quite a common verb used referring to circumstances or situations:

[To arise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arise):(int.)

> - to come into being; originate
> - to appear; spring up: *New problems arise daily*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circumstances%20arise%2Ccircumstances%20arose%2Csituations%20arise%2C%20situations%20arose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircumstances%20arise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircumstances%20arose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csituations%20arise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csituations%20arose%3B%2Cc0): circumstances arise/arose vs situations arise/arose

> - ‘If circumstances [arise](http://www.the42.ie/6-nations-ireland-wales-sean-obrien-774367-Jan2013/), and you might be forced to leave, then who knows’ – Sean O’Brien.

(www.the42.ie/6-nations-ireland-wales-sean-obrien)

> - However, thanks chiefly to the changes brought about in the world sugar market by the Cuban Revolution, circumstances [arose](https://books.google.it/books?id=A9VQig2NXGEC&pg=PA139&dq=%22circumstances%20arose%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=H_NeVeKXLqPOyQOytYGwCA&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22circumstances%20arose%22&f=false) that altered the course of events.

(Diagnosis of the Brazilian Crisis)